# AspCore app multiple web configs same hosting

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

How can it be achieved, to host multiple websites in IIS, so that everyon of them has it's own web.config file, but they all share the same physical hosting path? So when I have (let's say) 400 websites, I just want to update them at once, which makes it alot faster of course...

I had something in mind like this:

[image: IIS hosting setup]

Basically I want to create a website on IIS, give it a web.config, and keep a seperate hosting folder, which will be included in my mutliple websites...

I'm always getting an 503 error, because (I guess) the aspcore app is not in the root folder of the website.

Comment: It is impossible.

Comment: So how does one add support for multi tenancy in AspCore? I need a website with exactly 1 publish and multiple clients. Each client should have a specific port in IIS and a specific database connection linked to it...

I opened another question about this topic, but I could not resolve it. We still have no solution for this problem so far, and time urges

Comment: The reason why we chose this solution is, because we could give each website a unique web.config, which inculdes the database name as an environment variable. We see no other chance to select the database on StartUp depending on the port of the URL, because the host is created AFTER the asp site ist started

Comment: Spend some time on IIS configuration system, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7#hierarchy and you can find other places (like location tags in `applicationHost.config` to store per site settings. (BTW, "multi tenancy" usually does not require multiple IIS sites, but a single one.)

Comment: I had a brief look over this, but this doesn't help me at all. First, I need a database set correctly before Kestrel launches my website. My users are in the specific client-databases, which means when the SignInManager from Identity is loaded, I must provide him a set of users. This happens before my host is created. Hence why I need to use multiple websites in IIS, to create correct Hosts.

And I see no option to give a site parameters depending it's port in IIS. Ontop virtual directories are not working with Kestrel, if we use them it will just crash, as the directory wasn't recognized.